# When using a jQuery "loader screen," rest of Bootstrap HTML is not hidden

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently facing an issue with using a simple jQuery loading screen before being brought to my main site. I attempted to use `display: none;` on the body of the text to make it remain hidden, but instead it caused the entirety of the site to not be displayed.

The script that I am using is an incredibly simple jQuery script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loader").delay(2700).fadeOut(900, function() {
        $("#portfolio").fadeIn(400);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5f95rup/) and full demo as a snippet.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#loader" ).delay(1700).fadeOut(900, function(){
        $( "#portfolio" ).fadeIn(400);
    });
});
```

```css
.portfolio{
  background-color: white;
}

h1{
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20%;
  font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
  color: #FDFEFE;
  font-size: 7em;
}

.background{
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

body{
  background-color: white;
}

ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 47.5%;
  padding: 0%;
  width: 5%;
  background-color: #F4ECF7;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active{
  background-color: #D7BDE2;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active){
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.picture1{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div id="loader">
  <div class="container-fluid background">
  <h1>To A Beautiful World of Code</h1>
</div>
</div>
</body>


<body>
<div id= "portfolio">

<div class="container-fluid picture1">
  <img src= "<--! image-->" style= "width:45%;height:15%;"></img>
</div>


<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

I did notice that under the DevTools from Chrome, the entirety of the site (including the loading screen) was being stuffed into a single body (`<body ==$0`). I have attempted to separate the loading screen and actual page contents into two different bodies to no avail.

I appreciate any help and input!

Comment: Did you already check your own code? It is bit of a mess, some div's are not closed our you're using ID in the HTML and then style it in CSS like classes.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. It's my first time trying to integrate Jquery, and I guess I haven't been as thorough checking up through my errors!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the validity of your HTML using, for example, the [W3C service](https://validator.w3.org/).
2. Check the validity of your CSS using, for example, the [W3C service](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).
3. Make sure you apply your styles correctly using, for example, the DOM inspector of your browser (Google is your friend in finding out how that works).

Now to get to the point. It is invalid to have more than one `body` element on a page. Furthermore, a lot of your other styling is invalid.

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Justastudent/v5f95rup/1/) showing how you could have a loader screen the way you want to. The loader is set to take up the entire screen using `fixed` positioning and set to be in front of all the rest using a `z-index` that is high enough (a value of 2 sufficed in this case).

This is the relevant CSS.

```
#loader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

I also changed a `margin-top: 20%;` on `h1` to a `padding-top` on the `.background`, so that the loader actually covers the entire screen. A margin causes it to be shifted down a bit.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#loader").delay(1700).fadeOut(900, function() {
    $("#portfolio").fadeIn(400);
  });
});
```

```css
#loader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.portfolio {
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
  color: #FDFEFE;
  font-size: 7em;
}

.background {
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 20%;
  background-color: black;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 47.5%;
  padding: 0%;
  width: 5%;
  background-color: #F4ECF7;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
  background-color: #D7BDE2;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.picture1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="loader">
  <div class="container-fluid background">
    <h1>To A Beautiful World of Code</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="portfolio">
  <div class="container-fluid picture1">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/400" style="width:45%;height:15%;" />
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```